# TESTNG | call testng.xml file from main method from inside a runnable jar

Tags: java, maven, testng

I am new to testng + maven and I have requirement to run scripts using runnable jar. The suite needs to be executed for multiple regions . The region name is passed as an argument while executing jar. 
Now my requirement is to switch between multiple testng.xml files based on the region name provided.
All the testng.xml files are placed inside resource folder  --> "resources/testngA.xml" and "resources/testngB.xml".
When I run the script from eclipse it works fine but when i try to execute the same through runnable.jar it shows  **java.io.FileNotFoundException exception** . Can anyone please help me to fix this.

```
public class TestRunner {

    static TestNG testng;
    static List<String> suites;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String xmlFileName = "";
        List<XmlSuite> suite;
        String region = arg[0];
        try
        {
            if(region.equals("A")){
                xmlFileName = "resources/A_TestNG.xml";
            }else if(region.equals("B")){
                xmlFileName = "resources/B_TestNG.xml";
            }else{
                System.out.println("No matching region found")
            }
            suite = (List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser(xmlFileName).parse());
            testng.setXmlSuites(suite);
            testng.run();
        }
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you deal with resources you should use the following approach:

1) Take resource URI

```
URI aTestNgURI = TestRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResource("A_TestNG.xml").toURI();
```

2) Obtain path to a file

```
String aTestNgFilePath = new File(aTestNgURI).getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: I tried the same but getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at com.XXX.testcases.TestRunner.main(TestRunner.java:30)
 Code Snippet is as follow
URI aTestNgURI = TestRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/A_TestNG.xml").toURI();
String aTestNgFilePath = new File(aTestNgURI).getAbsolutePath();
suite = (List <XmlSuite>)(new Parser(aTestNgFilePath).parse());
testng.setXmlSuites(suite);
testng.run();

Comment: @Aswathi in your code I cannot see where you instantiate your `testng` field. Try `static TestNG testng = new TestNG()` instead of just ``static TestNG testng;`

Comment: Iam getting Nullpointer exception for below line"TestRunner.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/A_TestNG.xml").toURI();" and also testng variable is declared as static only

Comment: Regarding the exception you should not use `resources/`. Use just file name. Regarding static field: you have to assign an instance to that field either it is static or not.